# Onchange not working in loop

Tags: jquery, laravel, onchange

I am using Laravel 4.2. I have form inside a `foreach` statement:

```
@foreach($result as $key => $prices)
$endforeach
```

Inside this foreach loop I have a form:

```
<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">How many car?</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="number_of_car" id="car_no">
            <option value="" selected>select car numbers</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Method to pay?</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="payment_method" id="ad_tt">
            <option value="">Select Type</option>
            <option value="1">Full Payment</option>
            <option value="2">Advance Payment</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#car_no").change(function(){
        var number_of_car = $("#car_no option:selected").val();
        var payment_type = $("#ad_tt option:selected").val();
        var amount = "<?php $ad = $prices->totalAmount; echo 'Rs: '.$ad; ?>"; alert(amount);
    });
});
```

My problem is, when I change the option value of rows other than first loop, I get the value of first row only. But, I need to get the from the respective row. So, How could I do that using jquery.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use class instead of id since the id must be unique in DOM. Here you are triggering the change event for id = car_no, that you have to make unique by appending iterator value to the id.

```
$("#car_no").change(function() {} //should replace with 
$(".car_no").change(function(){
// use $(this).attr('data') to identify the element.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, when I alert, It is getting the value from the last looped statement. But, I want to display value from their respective loop.

Comment: What I am trying to display is the different amount for selecting different loop. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @vijayrana, have you gone through my answer

Comment: @Satpal Yeah I have gone through your answer. But Its not actually what I have wanted. I am getting amount value of last element only when I change the select option of first row( First looped element )

Comment: $prices is an object having array list inside it which received from api. Other works perfect, I am just stucked here

Answer (score 1):

**IDs in HTML must be unique.** This is expected behavior. Common classes can be used and use relationship to traverse the DOM using various methods.

Below I have used `car_no` and `ad_tt` as CSS class for `select` element

*HTML*

```
<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">How many car?</label>
        <select class="form-control car_no" name="number_of_car" data-amount="<?php $ad = $prices->totalAmount; echo 'Rs: '.$ad; ?>">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 slide_content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Method to pay?</label>
        <select class="form-control ad_tt" name="payment_method">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

*SCRIPT*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".car_no").change(function(){
        var number_of_car = $(this).val();
        var payment_type = $(this).closest('.slide_content').next('.slide_content').find(".ad_tt" ).val();

        var amount = $(this).data("amount");
        alert(amount);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I have gone through your answer. But Its not actually what I have wanted. I am getting amount value of last element only when I change the select option of first row( First looped element )

Comment: @vijayrana, You are using `amount = "<?php $ad = $prices->totalAmount; echo 'Rs: '.$ad; ?>"; ` so what do you expect to get __amout__ is being populated by php

Comment: Yeah, It is populating amount. The value of last looped amount is Rs: 38903. But when I change the option of First row(loop), I am getting Rs: 38903. I am supposed to get Rs: 3117

Comment: Thanks. Its perfectly working now. appreciate your help :)

Comment: I need to display the result in a div section. How could I do that? Here is my div section after select option inside loop.                                                                                                                                `
     
                                                    <div class="total_payment"></div>

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use id for more than one element. You have to use class.

```
<select class="form-control" name="number_of_car" class="car_no" >
```

and

```
var number_of_car = $(this).val();
```

similarly get the value for the other dropdown.